# Remove commas and newlines from text file in python

Tags: python

I have text file which looks like this:

```
ab initio
ab intestato
ab intra
a.C.
acanka, acance, acanek, acankach, acankami, acanką
Achab, Achaba, Achabem, Achabie, Achabowi
```

I would like to pars every word separated by comma into a list. So it would look like `['ab initio', 'ab intestato', 'ab intra','a.C.', 'acanka', ...]` Also mind the fact that there are words on new lines that are not ending with commas.
When I used 
`list1.append(line.strip())` it gave me string of every line instead of separate words. Can someone provide me some insight into this?

Full code below:

```
list1=[]
filepath="words.txt"
with open(filepath, encoding="utf8") as fp:  
   line = fp.readline()
   while line:
       list1.append(line.strip(','))
       line = fp.readline()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very close, but I think you want `split` instead of `strip`, and `extend` instead of `append`

You can also iterate directly over the lines with a for loop.

```
list1=[]
filepath="words.txt"
with open(filepath, encoding="utf8") as fp:  
   for line in fp:
       list1.extend(line.strip().split(', '))
```

Comment: wouldnt this lead to having `\n` in the splitted words?

Comment: Yeah actually it leaves \n at the end of the line splits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *your code* to get down to "list of line"-content and apply:

```
cleaned = [ x for y in list1 for x in y.split(',')]
```

this essentially takes any thing you parsed into your list and splits it at `,` to creates a new list.

[sberrys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48479267/7505395) all in one solution that uses no intermediate list is faster.

Comment: Alex also wants it split by newline from the example, not just by commas

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000  yep and he already solved this problem himself - this is just tackling the last part he had not yet solved. he solved it by using `readlines()` which also removes the `\n` from his files line.